# Regex in xsd assertion limited to beginning of element value

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I have created assertions in xsd schema 1.1 that contain regular expressions. The expressions are supposed to exclude roman numbers and numbers that have a period and space after them from beginning of value of the element. From what I have read, I don't need to anchor the regular expression in xsd schema b/c it should already apply to beginning (I may have misunderstood that). I am not able to limit the regular expressions to the beginning.

XSD:

```
   <xs:element name="node123">
         <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                       <xs:assertion test="not(matches($value, '[\d].*\.\s.|[I].*\.\s.*|[V].*\.\s.*|[X].*\.\s.*|[L].*\.\s.*|[C].*\.\s.*'))"/>
                       <xs:assertion test="not(starts-with($value, '-'))"/>
                       <xs:assertion test="not(starts-with($value, '–'))"/>
                       <xs:assertion test="not(starts-with($value, '—'))"/>
                </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
```

False positives are:

Mismash of Fid. R. Crim. Z

Shipped C. O. D

I can't use starts-with with the number expressions b/c that doesn't work at all. However, when I use starts-with with the other expressions, it doesn't apply to the whole element value.

Is there a way to limit the expressions to just the first words or start of the element?

Comment: Try a single `xs:assertion` with `test="not(matches($value, '([-–—]|[0-9IVXLC]+\.\s).*'))"`. If it does not behave as the regular XSD regex, try adding `^` at the start.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and is much cleaner than the one I took forever to come up with.

Comment: Didn't realize the regex did not actually work. So, no sense to keep an answer with the regex explanation.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, the regex you included worked with the addition of the ^ worked for the assertion. I just don't  have enough reputation points to indicate it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. XSD regular expressions in `xsd:pattern` facets ***are*** implicitly anchored at start (`^`) and end (`$`).
2. XPath regular expressions, which are utilized in `xsd:assertion` are ***not*** implicitly anchored.

Given the above, the regex [provided by @WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122713/regex-in-xsd-assertion-limited-to-beginning-of-element-value#comment102636704_58122713) (along with his advice to try adding `^`) is a reasonable approximation to your goal of excluding strings that look like Arabic or Romain numbers:

```
  <xs:element name="node123">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:assertion test="not(matches($value, '^([-–—]|[0-9IVXLC]+\.\s)'))"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that xpath regular expressions were not implicitly anchored in xsd:assertion. I will make note of that for future.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but don't have the reputation points yet to comment.  But you can force your regex to beginning by instead of doing this:

```
'[\d] ...
```

Do this:

```
'^\s*[\d] ..
```

The "^" forces the beginning, and the "\s*" handles any rogue white space.